# Execute Maven plugin with custom classpath entry

Tags: maven, classpath, maven-plugin

I would like to call a maven plugin with a custom entry on its classpath. This is usually possible by adding `<dependencies>` inside the `<plugin>` tag. The problem is, what I would like to add to the classpath is not a maven artifact, but some random folder in my project (the reasons for this are quite obscure, I need a resource file to be present of the classpath, but I must not copy it to the `/target/classes` due to IDE shenanigans).

Is there any way to specify *truly* arbitrary classpath entries for a maven plugin?

Comment: Btw, you can access any resource file in your project directly through absolute path from project base directory.

Comment: That would be useful, but I didn't write that plugin. I decided to try and modify the plugin anyways. However, in the meantime, I have to put up with errors in my IDE due to the resource being copied to /target/classes.

Comment: In general, you cannot have a _folder_ as a dependency.

Comment: A resource can be accessed via the usual locations `src/main/resources` or in case of test resources `src/test/resources`...FUrthermore if your plugin needs such things on a classpath it should handle that on it's own which mean to define a default location where such things are located and put that on the classpath. Furthermore what purpose does this plugin have?

Comment: xtext-maven-plugin: https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-maven/tree/master/org.eclipse.xtext.maven.plugin it traverses the classpath entries and puts any Xtext models it finds into an EMF ResourceSet. I need the ResourceSet to contain something which does not get copied over to /target/classes. Furthermore, I use tycho, so no `src/main/resources` for me, Eclipse PDE uses bin.includes in build.properties instead, but it gets ignored when calculating the classpaths of Maven plugins.

Comment: My question was inspired by this Eclipse bug, to be precise: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=487683 I was interested whether there existed a tool for working around these kinds of issues in general. In this case, it was enough to patch the plugin a bit, but I expect to run into similar issues with Tycho and exotic Maven plugin combinations, unfortunately...